# Ffmpeg program to stitch image side by side

Tags: ffmpeg, image-editing

So I have about 90-100 images which are of the resolution 1080x1920px. I want to make a program in ffmpeg that will join them as in stitch them side by side(horizontally), such that all the images combine to become a wide image. Can someone pls help me with a program for this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/290656/combine-multiple-images-using-imagemagick